# Webpack: load different filenames according to argument

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to achieve the following with webpack:

I have webpack loading scss files modularly in my javascript and would like to be able to use different files depending on argument passed to webpack

For example, I would like to be able to import my styles like this:

```
import "./foo.scss"
```

and have webpack import `./foo.projectA.scss` if I pass it an argument saying `projectA`, or `./foo.projectB.scss` if argument is `projectB`.

I'm fairly sure that this is possible to do, but having spent an hour reading the docs I am none-the-wiser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use an [alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) for this.

Comment: You might have to elaborate. I can see that you could probably do something like this `{ 'foo.scss$': './foo.projectA.scss' }` for each file, But that doesn't feel viable when we have many scss modules scattered through the project.

Answer (score 0):

Ar compile time Webpack will need to know all the *potential* files you could require.  That way it can assign a module number for them, and have them available at runtime.

For example if you have a directory called **styles** with three files you could potentially require.

```
/styles
    ./projectA.scss
    ./projectB.scss
    ./main.scss
```

First you would create a [context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) for the directory

```
var moduleMap = require("./styles/" + projectName + ".scss");
```

This returns a map of files to their module Ids.  You can then use this map in code to require the proper scss at runtime.

```
var projectName= 'projectA';
moduleMap('./' + projectName + '.scss');
```

Givin the above example, projectA.scss will be loaded.  Then you can use the
[DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) to specify the project type if it's determined during compilation.

Comment: `var moduleMap = require("./styles/" + projectName + ".scss");` --- are you sure this will work? Where does the `projectName` come from?

Comment: Yes. Webpack parses the requires and determines the statement is dynamic.  It then extracts what it can about the path to build its context. See https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html